# JS .toggle navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

sorry, can't get my head around whats gone wrong here. I'm trying to take an existing nav bar from a site and implement it on another one but nothing I've tried is working. I've managed to salvage this from it...

Java Script

```
 $(function() {
$('#menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('#menu-main-menu').slideToggle('fast');

    var toggleIcon = $('#menu-toggle i');
    if((toggleIcon).is('.fa-bars')) {
        toggleIcon.addClass('fa-times')
        toggleIcon.removeClass('fa-bars')
    } else {
        toggleIcon.removeClass('fa-times')
        toggleIcon.addClass('fa-bars')

    }
});
```

Code

```
<div class="container-body">
        <div class="logo">
            <div id="menu-toggle" class="pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php if(get_theme_mod('site_logo')) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('site_logo'); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"></a><?php } else { ?><h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name') ?></h1></div><?php } ?>
        <nav class="navbar custom-nav" id="top-menu"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-menu')); ?></nav>
    </div>
```

So, I have a copy of it working but after multiple attempts at trying to look through it, I just can't figure it out. What currently happens at the moment is when you click on it nothing happens. Whereas on the other site it folds down. I even copied the old jQuery from that website to see if it would work but no hope. If someone could help that would be brill!

UPDATE **

Heres the full generated code.

```
<nav class="navbar custom-nav" id="top-menu">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="">Massage At Work</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="">Treatments</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="">Gift Cards</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="">Team</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="">Feedback</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="">Book</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-58"><a href=""></a></li><li class="social-icon"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-59"><a href=""></a></li><li class="social-icon"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul></div></div></nav>
```

Comment: Are there any console errors?  Can you share the generated HTML instead of the PHP code?  We can't tell what HTML you're actually working with as it is now.

Comment: You can use .toggleClass() to avoid all of the those conditionals

Comment: Hi @Daniel I've updated the code :)

Comment: Also, no console errors

Comment: @JoelHager Yes, once I got it working I was going to get rid of the conditionals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've just found out why, I feel stupid :) The Navbar ID was set differently to the one in the code, but is all working now!